# PgAdmin 4 password-less connection to local database via unix socket

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have initialized a pg database as such:

```sh
user_name@my_machine$ sudo -u postgres createuser -s user_name
user_name@my_machine$ createdb -T template0 db_name
```

I can now connect to it via `psql` via `user_name@my_machine$ psql db_name`
and everything works well with the CLI tooling.

The relevant auth line of `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` is:
`local all all peer`

Now I'd like to connect to it via PgAdmin 4, and I can't find a way to tell the interface that I want to connect via unix socket and don't need a password.
The sanest way I can think is:
[image: Connection dialog][image: Advanced Dialog]

but the connection is still rejected with a `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.

I know I could configure a password for my user and give it, but I'd like to know if I can make PgAdmin behave properly.

Comment: @Steeeve that solved the issue. Wouldn't have guessed it, with the documentation promising that <empty hostname> = <default unix socket>. Please make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: But what documentation?  Leaving both host fields empty would work (on Linux), if PgAdmin4 didn't go out of its way to disable it.

Comment: @jjanes I can't find it anymore, I may have confused some SO posts with the official docs, which do state that you can use an address or a unix socket, but say nothing about leaving it empty. It's not ideal, but I don't plan on changing the default socket ever, so it's fine this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: put `/var/run/postgresql` in `host name/address`.

Comment: Still, the best answer, a lot of answers said to add a new password via psql command but I just want it to work without adding a password.